# RF interference on GPIO?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, interference

Novice here.

I think I have an RF interference problem with a 3.3v digital device used to control lights via an API over wifi and need some help making sense of it.

I have an esp8266 based device with one GPIO input having a 30k pull up resistor and a pair of two-way switches connected. These switches either connect ground, pulling the GPIO low, or are open, letting the resistor pull the GPIO high.

3.3v and ground (GND) are provided by an LDO regulator and an AC to DC transformer.

The esp8266 will toggle lights on or off (via the API over wifi) whenever the GPIO changes state and it’s configured in the software to debounce with a 100ms delay.

The problem is the lights are intermittently flickering off and on, sometimes continuously. The debug logs on the device reveal the GPIO input is changing so I don’t think it’s an issue with the lights or API and I’m assuming this is due to EMI in the switch wires, but I might be wrong.

When pulled low the switch wires make a loop from GND to the GPIO. It is approximately 3m to the first switch and another 5m to the second. The cables contain 3 or 4 wires of 1.5mm2 solid copper, one wire is earth which is bound to the metal boxes on which the physical switches are located. (This is all standard for two way switch wiring and it would be capable of directly switching 230v, but that’s not what I want it for).

My guess is when the switches are open they might be forming an antenna (a kind of monopole but without the ground?) of either 3m or 3+5=7m long. When the switches are closed there is a 14m loop from GND to the GPIO. The flickering seems to happen in both scenarios but definitely in the open “antenna” scenario.

These cables run along side several mains cables carrying 230v 50hz mains AC. They don’t terminate in the same places but they do run parallel for most their length.

I have the same circuit working well for several one way switches and, apart from being one way, the main difference is the short wire length. it is only 5cm from the GPIO to the switch.

My questions are:

1. Could this long switch wire set up result in mains AC inducing noise in the circuit and is this just as likely to happen in either the GND connected or floating scenarios?
2. If there is AC interference why is it so intermittent? It can go for hours with no issue then flicker once, twice or 100s of times.
3. If it’s not AC interference could it be any other RF? Like many people I’ve got plenty of RF in the house including wifi, FM, AM, DAB, TV, 433mhz, baby monitor, etc, etc. But I didn’t expect 7m of copper wiring to pick it up, and again I don’t see why the interference from this would be so intermittent.
4. I’ve read RF signals can induce high voltages in an antenna so I must admit I’m nervous putting my old oscilloscope on it to try and see the kind interference. Am I right to worry? Could this setup result in high voltage or high current? It doesn’t make sense to me if 14m of wire in a normal house could cause high voltages from normal RF but having read lots of articles about antenna which warn about high voltage I feel I should check!
5. If this is RF interference is it likely, or almost certainly, common mode? All the cables in question house the “from GND” and “to GPIO” wires in parallel. If it is common mode do I need to think about managing the noise on the GND connection just as much as noise on the GPIO?
6. I’ve read about solutions to protect the GPIO from interference. Firstly a low pass RC filter, to cut frequencies above 50hz. Secondly, using steering diodes and a TVS diode (e.g. as provided by the SRDA3.3 package). The RC filter introduces a resistor before the GPIO which might help limit current from transients, is that a good idea even without the capacitor? (I’ve never need this in my other circuits.) By my maths a low pass RC that cuts 50hz and above will introduce a few hundred ms delay to tigger the GPIO low so might need to tune the debounce down to compensate. I didn’t want to just add these components to the circuit without understanding the situation properly but does this design sound sensible? Or overkill? Or not good enough?
7. What about a ferrite bead / chock as an alternative or in addition to the RC filter? You see these a lot on old PC interface cables, or laptop chargers, so I don’t imagine they do much to filter out 50hz. In my case might they protect against other transients or common mode interference? Again is this sensible? Overkill? No point?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this happen only in certain switch position or not? What kind of switch is it? Just thinking aloud here that 30k pull up is very weak, your wires may run neart 50Hz mains wiring, and depends how you do debouncing with100ms period, it can synchronously read mains frequency interference.

Comment: It happens in both positions. The 2x two-way switches are “Hager Sollysta 1 Gang 2 Way Light Switch White” they are designed for 230v ac switching (10a) but I’m using them for digital switching here just for the aesthetics. Debounce is done using esphome’s binary sensor delay_on: 100ms setting - basically won’t turn on unless the GPIO is held in position for for over 100ms.

Comment: It’s behaving really erratically, making me wonder if the esp8266 chip has been damaged in some way. But if it has, all my questions above still stand because I need to rebuild it in a way the new one can’t get damaged next time.

Comment: Thats very likely the problem, I had something like this happen once on a system I insalled. Try disconnecting the wires at the input and let it run for a while and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I’ve been doing some experimenting and it’s making even less sense. I have found:

Comment: 1. Connecting an oscilloscope ground to the microcontroller ground goes bang! Lucky my scope survived… and I learnt a lesson about ground loops.

Comment: 2. The scope shows 5v peak to peak, 50hz AC (so ~1.75v rms) across the two switch wires when they are open (E.g floating / acting as an antenna). And flat line when they are closed (E.g. wires form a closed loop). I’m amazed so much voltage can be inducted in floating wires, is this normal?
- My multimeter on AC voltage mode shows 0.5V AC across two switch wires which is strange, I would have expected the 1.75v rms. Don’t understand why I’m seeing somthing different on the scope.

Comment: 3. The multimeter reads 1.8v when tested against the scope’s 2V square wave calibration signal which seems reasonable.

Comment: So still believe there is an AC interference issue which was really what my original question was about. Any advice or answers very much appreciated!